# Error In Async Closure: lifetime may not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying to build a discord bot, i got this `thread_local!()` global variable
`thread_local!(static USER_DATA: RefCell<HashMap<u64, String>> = RefCell::new(HashMap::new()));` and i got the error when trying to access the variable with an async closure like below which is in a function

```
USER_DATA.with(|data| async {
        if data.borrow().contains_key(msg.author.id.as_u64()) {
            let binusmaya_api = BinusmayaAPI{token: data.borrow().get(msg.author.id.as_u64()).unwrap().clone()};
            let schedule: String = binusmaya_api.get_schedule().await.expect("something's wrong");
            msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http, |m| {
                m.embed(|e| e
                    .colour(0x03aaf9)
                    .field("Schedule", schedule, false)
                )
            }).await.unwrap();
        } else {
            msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http, |m| {
                m.embed(|e| e
                    .colour(0x03aaf9)
                    .field("You're not registered", "please register first using `=register` command", false)
                )
            }).await.unwrap();
        }
    });
```

here is the error logs

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/discord.rs:240:24
    |
240 |       USER_DATA.with(|data| async {
    |  _____________________-----_^
    | |                     |   |
    | |                     |   return type of closure `impl std::future::Future` contains a lifetime `'2`
    | |                     has type `&'1 RefCell<HashMap<u64, std::string::String>>`
241 | |         if data.borrow().contains_key(msg.author.id.as_u64()) {
242 | |             let binusmaya_api = BinusmayaAPI{token: data.borrow().get(msg.author.id.as_u64()).unwrap().clone()};
243 | |             let schedule: String = binusmaya_api.get_schedule().await.expect("something's wrong");
...   |
257 | |         }
258 | |     });
    | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

error: could not compile `BINUSMAYA_Discord_Bot` due to previous error
```

I didn't know how to solve this problem because i cannot change the lifetime freely, should i change how i declare the global variable instead? i don't want to do the unsafe way, that's why i use `thread_local!()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.with()` method is synchronous (the docs don't mention `async` or Future). So it expects a synchronous block. Using `async/await` inside seem wrong.

It is possible to first copy out the token like so:

```
let token_opt: Option<String> = USER_DATA.with(|data| {
    data.borrow().get(msg.author.id.as_u64()).clone()
});
```

Note that `.get()` returns an Option already, so it saves an extra `if` inside.

Then use `token_opt` in your async code:

```
match token_opt {
    Some(token) => {
        let binusmaya_api = BinusmayaAPI{token: token};
        let schedule: String = binusmaya_api.get_schedule().await.expect("something's wrong");
        msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http, |m| {
            m.embed(|e| e
                .colour(0x03aaf9)
                .field("Schedule", schedule, false)
            )
        }).await.unwrap();
    }
    None => {
        msg.channel_id.send_message(&ctx.http, |m| {
            m.embed(|e| e
                .colour(0x03aaf9)
                .field("You're not registered", "please register first using `=register` command", false)
            )
        }).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Note that thread_local means that each thread makes its own copy of USER_DATA, so if this code is run from multiple threads, some threads won't have the token unless you have added it before using the same thread.

Comment: interesting, i've never thought about using a variable to store the data before, thanks for the solution